# Find relation between the vectors

Tags: geometry, vectors

'a', 'b', 'c' and 'd' are vectors. It has been given that:

i) a x b = c x d 
ii) a x c = b x d 
iii) a≠d and b≠c

**Q**: (a - d) is _________ to (b - c) 
a. Parallel   b. Perpendicular   c. Equal

Comment: is the answer a?

Comment: Yes, the answer is a. How that?

Comment: Can you find $(a-d)\times (b-c)$?

Comment: Yup, it comes out to be zero, hence parallel. Cheers, mate